# How can I load my Aurelia app from an index.html which is not located in the same folder as the rest of the application?

Tags: javascript, python, web2py, aurelia, jspm

How can I load my app from an `index.html` which is not located in the same folder as the rest of the application?

I’m currently using `jspm` (which I’m new to). I’m trying to integrate `Aurelia` with `web2py` (Python web framework).

My `index.html` in accessible via

```
http://websiteaddress.com/myapp/default/index.html
```

and may later be accessible via

```
http://websiteaddress.com/myapp/index.html
```

but the code of my `Aurelia` app is accessible from

```
http://websiteaddress.com/myapp/static/aurelia_app/
```

On the disk the `index.html` file is at

```
/web2py/applications/myapp/views/default/index.html
```

and the `Aurelia` app folder is at

```
/web2py/applications/myapp/static/aurelia_app
```

Comment: Hi Alexei, can you describe better what you want to achieve?

Comment: Hi @Cesar,

A web2py app has this folder structure:

controllers
views
static

JavaScript files are stored in the static folder, and the html files are stored in the views folder.

I can also store html files in the static folder but doing so I lose integration with the web2py controllers and view templates.

I would like to store the main index.html file in the standard views folder and initialize my Aurelia app (which is stored in the static folder) from there.

The index.html file in the views folder is normally accessible via www.myapp.com/appname/controllername/index.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the [web2py pattern router](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/04/the-core?search=router#Pattern-based-system), something like this in the router definition should work:

```
routes_in = (
  ('/appname/default/index', '/appname/static/aurelia_app/index.html'),
  ('/appname/default/jspm_packages/$anything', '/appname/static/aurelia_app/jspm_packages/$anything'),
)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work.

The app fails to load resources that are located at `/syncfusion_app1/static/aurelia_app/jspm_packages/npm/bluebird@3.4.1/js/browser/bluebird.min.js`

Instead it tries to load them from `/syncfusion_app1/default/jspm_packages/npm/bluebird@3.4.1/js/browser/bluebird.min.js`

Here is how the bluebird file is referenced from index.html
`<script src="jspm_packages/npm/bluebird@3.4.1/js/browser/bluebird.min.js"></script>`

Comment: @AlexeiVinidiktov, that's because you need to add more rules, the answer is updated whith an example, but, what is the relation of the aurelia app with web2py? is aurelia the frontend and web2py the backend?, in my opinion will be better serve them separately

Comment: thanks, I'll try adding more rules and report back. The Aurelia app is the front-end and web2py is the backend.